# Subquery dentro de un callback javascript y mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, base-de-datos, nodejs

Buenas a todos intento obtener los detalles de una tabla foránea después de hacer una consulta, realizo un ciclo for para recorrer todos los resultados de la consulta principal y realizar una sub consulta con los datos de el id foráneo, esto desde un servidor en express usando mysql como sgdb.

```
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM producto ORDER BY idproducto DESC LIMIT '+per_page+' OFFSET '+offset+'';
  db.query(sql).then((results) =>{
    productos = [];
    if(results.length > 0){
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var item = results[i];
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE idcategoria = ?';
        db.query(sql, item.categoria).then((result) => {
          if(result.length > 0){
            item.categoria = result;
          }else{
            item.categoria = null;
          }
          productos.push(item);
        });
      }
      console.log(productos);
      res.status(200).send({
        productos: productos
      });
    }else{
      res.status(404).send({
        message: 'Sin registros'
      });
    }
  });
```

Según los logs de la consola los datos se ordenan correctamente, pero al finalizar el subquery y colocar el objeto de datos en otro array para enviarlo por el servidor estos no llegan al array y en el navegador se muetsra vacío.

¿Alguna idea o comentario? tengo muy poco de estar con tecnologías javascript y recién encontré el cliente de conexión con mysql.
Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: empiezas usando promesas y luego cambias a callbacks

Answer (score 0):

tu codigo para que sea mejor usas las promesas aqui un ejemplo.

```
function consultaCategoria(id_categoria){
  return new Promise(function (resolve , reject) {
    db.query(sql, item.categoria).then((result) => {
            if(result.length > 0){
              item.categoria = result;
            }else{
              item.categoria = null;
            }
            resolve(item);
          });
})
function consultarProducto(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve , reject) {
    db.query(sql).then((results) =>{
      resolve(results)

    })
  })
}

consultarProducto().then((results) =>{
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
     consultaCategoria(result.results[i]).then((item) =>{
       productos.push(item)
   }
   return productos;
}).then((productos) =>{
  res.status(200).send({
        productos: productos
      });
})
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, ya aplique las promesas desde la clase pero sigo obteniendo el arreglo vacío desde la clase y el log de la consola muestra que la información si esta en el arreglo.

Comment: probablemente esta un error alli

Answer (score 0):

Si es un buen aporte, pero relacionado a este tema me gustaria como almacenar este campo relacional. Mi interfaz del articulo está así...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El problema surge desde del método POST cuando ya quiero Guardar...
  Me sale este error
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi cod del lado del servidor del POST

postNewArticulo : function(req, res, next){
      req.assert('nombre', 'Nombre Obligatorio de ingresar!!').notEmpty();
      req.assert('codigo', 'Codigo Obligatorio de ingresar!!').notEmpty();
      req.assert('categoria', 'Categoria Obligatorio de ingresar!!').notEmpty();
      req.assert('stock', 'Stock Obligatorio de ingresar!!').notEmpty();
      req.assert('imagen', 'Imágen Obligatorio de ingresar!!').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (!errors) {
                                                      //sanitize('') => desinfecta las ubicaciones de solicitud especificadas, 
                                                      //Ej que no este empty, String dond es...
     v_nombre = req.sanitize( 'nombre' ).escape().trim(); // escape() Sirve para que la Column 'name' cannot be null
     v_codigo= req.sanitize( 'codigo' ).escape().trim();// trim() Sirve para que propiedad de un campo se defina 'trim' of undefined
       v_categoria = req.sanitize( 'categoria' ).escape().trim(); // escape() Sirve para que la Column 'name' cannot be null
     v_stock= req.sanitize( 'stock' ).escape().trim();// trim() Sirve para que propiedad de un campo se defina 'trim' of undefined
     v_imagen = req.sanitize( 'imagen' ).escape().trim(); // escape() Sirve para que la Column 'name' cannot be null

```
var art = {
  nombre: v_nombre,
  codigo: v_codigo,
  categoria: v_categoria,
  stock: v_stock,
  imagen: v_imagen,
  descripcion:v_descripcion

   }
var categoria= 0
var config = require('../database/config');
var cnn = mysql.createConnection(config);


cnn.connect();
var queryAsync = Promise.promisify(cnn.query.bind(cnn));

   queryAsync('INSERT INTO Articulo SET ?', art)
   .then(function(results){
    categoria=results[0]
    //console.log(categoria)
   //cnn.query('INSERT INTO Articulo SET ?', art , function(err, rows, fields){

     if(err) throw err;
  req.flash('msg_info', 'Artículo Registrado exitosamente!!!');
  cnn.end();
  res.render('almacen/articulo/create', {
  categoria:categoria
  });
})


 //})
```

}else {
    var errorDetalles = "

Lo siento, hay Errores!!!

";

```
for(i in errors){

  error= errors[i];
  errorDetalles+= '<li>'+error.msg+'</li>'; 
  }
  errorDetalles+= '</ul>';

req.flash('msg_error', errorDetalles);

 res.render('almacen/articulo/create', {

 });
```

}

},

### Y este es mi codigo del lado del Cliente....

#### Nueva Artículo

```
      <% if(messages.msg_error) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong><%- messages.msg_error%></strong> <br></br>

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
              <%}%>
     </div>       
  </div>
```

Nombre
                
            

            
                
                
                Categoría
            
              
                    ">
            

              
            
            

            
                 
                Código
                
            
            

            
                
                Stock
                
            
            

            
            
                Descripción
                
            
            

            
            
                Imagen
                
            
            
            
            
              Guardar
              Cancelar

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.